# CSS height 100% percent not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

I have a div with `height: 100%;` but it's not working. When I declare a fixed height (for example `height: 600px;`) it is working, but I would like a responsive design.

html:

```html
<blink><div class="row-fluid split-pane fixed-left" style="position: relative; height: 78%;">
    <div class="split-pane-component" style="position: relative; width: 50em;">
        <div style="">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#html" data-toggle="tab">Html</a></li>
                <li><a href="#helpers" data-toggle="tab">Helpers</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="html" style="height: 100%;">
                    <textarea id="htmlArea" style="height: 100%;">{{:html}}</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="helpers" style="height: 100%;">
                    <textarea id="helpersArea">{{:helpers}}</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="split-pane-divider" id="my-divider" style="left: 50em; width: 5px;"></div>
    <div class="split-pane-component" style="left: 50em; margin-left: 5px;">
        <div style="">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="active">Preview
                    <img width="22px" height="16px" class="preview-loader" src="img/spinner-green2.gif" style="display: none" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" style="height: 100%;">
                    <iframe name="previewFrame" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</blink>
```

Comment: iframes don't have automatic heights. you have to get it with javascript and define it. if you want it responsive you can use a window resize function

Comment: [Origin of the blink tag](http://www.montulli.org/theoriginofthe%3Cblink%3Etag)

Answer (score 52):

You probably need to declare the code below for `height:100%` to work for your divs

```
html, body {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
```

> fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5KYC3/

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 24):

You aren't specifying the "height" of your html. When you're assigning a percentage in an element (i.e. divs) the css compiler needs to know the size of the parent element. If you don't assign that, you should see divs without height.

The most common solution is to set the following property in css:

```
html{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

You are saying to the html tag (html is the parent of all the html elements) "Take all the height in the HTML document"

I hope I helped you. Cheers

Comment: How do I assign an element's height relative to the height of the page?

Answer (score 10):

I would say you have two options:

1. to get all parent divs styled with `100%` height (including body and html)
2. to use absolute positioning for one of the parent divs (for example `#content`) and then all child divs set to height `100%`

Comment: Position fixed works too.

Answer (score 7):

Set the containing element/div to a height.  Otherwise your asking the browser to set the height to 100% of an unknown value and it can't.

More info here:  http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm

Comment: it's not unknown, browser has computed value of each element. It's NOT unknown

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to make sure that all the container div tags above the 100% height div also has 100% height set on them including the body tag and html.

Answer (score 0):

For code mirror divs refer to the manual, these sections might be useful to you:

http://codemirror.net/demo/fullscreen.html

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  theme: "night",
  extraKeys: {
    "F11": function(cm) {
      cm.setOption("fullScreen", !cm.getOption("fullScreen"));
    },
    "Esc": function(cm) {
      if (cm.getOption("fullScreen")) cm.setOption("fullScreen", false);
    }
  }
});
```

And also take a look at:

http://codemirror.net/demo/resize.html

Also a comment:

Inline styling is horrible you should avoid this at all costs, not only will it confuse you, it's poor practice.

Answer (score 0):

Night's answer is correct

```
 html, body {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
```

Also check that your div or element is NOT inside another one (with height less than 100%)
Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Answer is correct. html, body must be height 100%. The div you want has to be 100% + all the parents between body and the div you want to set.