# Full height with skeleton boilerplate

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am trying to make every section tag have a height of 100%, but it does not work.

**Here is my html code:**

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="twelve columns">
        <section>
          <h4>Basic Page</h4>
          <p>This index.html page is a placeholder with the CSS, font and favicon. It's just waiting for you to add some content! If you need some help hit up the <a href="http://www.getskeleton.com">Skeleton documentation</a>.</p>
        </section>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
section {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

***skeleton.css and normalize.css is as downloaded***

Comment: please provide relevant css when asking a question about your css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`height: 100%;` is relative to the parent's `height`. That means if you haven't set the parent elements' `height`, `100%` of undefined, is undefined.

You will need to set an explicit `height` for `.twelve` element (and if that is a `%`, then for it's parents and so forth).

Also see these:

[height: 100% not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/height100-not-working)

[CSS height 100% percent not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357238/css-height-100-percent-not-working)

Comment: Hi @Scope if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `html, body {height: 100%;}` then the `.container` to 100% and then the `section`'s positioning to absolute to achieve that as the height in percentage is calculated relatively to its parent/container.

You could set your section to `height: 100vh;` to achieve that. Just be careful with paddings and margins, as the section could grow bigger than the viewport. :)

[Made a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/faloni/edit?html,css,output). *without skeleton

- I don't think it has anything to do with 'skeleton'.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrduUUdxBSY) is the best video to understand css units.