# Vertical centering not working because row not going to 100% height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to vertically center some divs in a bootstrap container that can resize due to another columns content. I want to do this without flexbox for backwards compatibility.

I am trying the translateY() trick but the parent row has 0 height so it centers itself on the top of the row instead of the middle.

I have read that floated items take the height of their children so I tried floating them but it still doesn't take the height.

How can I get this row to go 100% so the vertical centering works correctly?

```css
    .container{
      margin-top: 60px;
    }

    .outer, .container{
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .row-center{
      position: relative;
      /* This needs to be 100% height but I can't figure it out */
      /* I added the floats but it didn't help */
      height: 100%;
      float: left;
    }

    .outer{
      position: absolute;
      float: left;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x500"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-7 row-center">
          <div class="outer">
            <div class="one">some text</div>
            <div class="two">some text</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

(example code assumes that bootstrap css is referenced)

Code pen with bootstrap attached: http://codepen.io/GuerrillaCoder/pen/obJEgB

Comment: Did you try giving height of 100% to html and body.

Comment: This is a snippet from a page.  It is not the whole page.

Comment: @Guerilla http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357238/css-height-100-percent-not-working

Comment: Honestly, this isn't the issue.  The row is taking its height from the image and not being constrained by the body or html tags.  I did try this after you suggested just in case but it had no effect.

Comment: Do you have any links. or fiddle.

Comment: @Guerrilla You want set "some text" vertical center inside row?

Comment: @ketan I want it to be the centre of the image to the left of it or in other words center of the height of ".row"

Comment: code pen: http://codepen.io/GuerrillaCoder/pen/obJEgB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `position: unset;` to `.row-center` and `position:relative;` to `.row` will work for you.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2965hzno/)**

Comment: Nice!  Was it something in the bootstrap css causing issue?

Comment: @Guerrilla No. i have already added bootstrap in fiddle. And it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.outer, .container{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle;
    padding: 5px;
}

.row-center{
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

If this do not work then apply `padding` for that `div`.

Comment: @Krish : use  vertical-align: middle; :) One can use padding also.

Comment: try using padding.. I have edited my code. you can modify padding according to your block.

Comment: still doesn't work, I am not sure what you are trying to do here.  The issue is the row has 0 height so centrally aligning wont work until it is 100% height.  The issue is it's not taking height of child items.

Comment: you have to define width also here. set width:auto or width:100% as per your requirement.

Comment: height:500px; and remove width from css in _.row-center_

Comment: The whole point is I can't set manual height.  If I could set the height manually then it would be easy.

Comment: it is taking 503px height. and if want to align your text in center then apply padding to your class _One_ and _Two_