# Css % with height

Tags: html, css

Here is the example i'm testing on :
[Bootstrap starter theme](http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-one-page-wonder/)

You can try with inspect element.
Why cant i change height of `header` tag or the background image of it with `%`?
I have tried using px and it works like that.For example `height:800px;`
But if i use `height:80%;` it wont work. Can someone explain how this works ? I don't know what am i doing wrong.

Comment: For the `header` to respect a height given in percent, its parent also must have a `height`, and if that as well is given in percent, the next parent etc. Can you tell if that is the case? ... One often ends up with this rule `html, body { margin: 0; height: 100%; }`

Comment: Possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262852/css-height-in-percent-not-working  and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642866/height-percentage-not-working-in-css and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357238/css-height-100-percent-not-working

Comment: @LGSon Yeah,this was missing `html, body { margin: 0; height: 100%; }`.Tnx a lot mate,saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

When you are giving height is % value its reffere also to parent of this element. If you want to force header to have  80 % of screen height you have to take it out of the DOM flow by setting it as `position:absolute`.

So css can look like this :

```
.header-image {
position: absolute;
height: 80%;
}
```

Comment: That is not true, as it depends on if the parent has positioning.