# Set Dojo's Button height in %?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to create a dojo Button and set it inside a spanned on 2 rows table cell toking the whole presented height inside it, anyway due some reason it does not works.

```
require( [  "dijit/form/Button" , "dojo/dom", "dojo/parser"],
  function(  Button, dom, parser )
  {
     var buttonExecuteQuery = new Button(
     {
           id        : "btnExecuteQuery",
           busyLabel : "Изпълнява",
           label     : "Изпълни",                    
           style     : "height:100%",
           height    : "100%"
     });
})
```

- How to setup Dojo's Button height ?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way following your syntax is `style: "height:100%"`

```
var buttonExecuteQuery = new Button(
    {
        id        : "btnExecuteQuery",
        busyLabel : "Изпълнява",
        label     : "Изпълни",                    
        style     : "height:100%"
    }
);
```

`height: "100%"` does nothing. Now, the most important part, you need to understand that `height: "100%"` only works if the height of the parent is known, for example, if you want the button to occupy the full height of a div, then you must set the height of that div

```
<div style="height: 50px">
    <button style="height: 100%">My Button</button>
</div>
```

the are a lot of discussion of this topic here in SO, for example you can read
[Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)
[height:100%; not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/height100-not-working)
[CSS height 100% percent not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357238/css-height-100-percent-not-working)

Hope it helps

Comment: Hello Castro Roy. On which version of dojo this works ? Because it does not work seems like on v10. ( or maybe it's my mistake ). It works only if I do clean html/js

Comment: I'm testing with dojo `1.10`. If you pass it in the constructor, `new Button({style: "height:100%"})`, check your html, it will be there, then, you just need to follow the other links a gave to make `height:100%` works, make sense? Also, you can use a css class if you don't want to use inline style

Comment: can You post in https://jsfiddle.net playground the source You are testing please.