# In Firefox, img is a child element, and the height is set to 100%, but the width of the parent element is the original width of the img

Tags: html, css, firefox

#### Browser version

> Firefox 79.0

When `img` is used as a child element, and its height is set to 100% of the parent element, the expected phenomenon is that the width of the parent element is determined by the img. Eventually, in the `Firefox` browser, the `img` is scaled proportionally, but the width of the parent element is the child element original width. I can get the expected result in Google browser. The code show as below.

```html
<div class="outer-est">
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="outer_container">
                <div class="content_panel">
                    <div class="icon_panel">
                        <a href="" class="link_btn">
                            <img src="img/join_us/email.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
<style>
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .outer-est {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .outer {
            width: 62.5%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .outer_container {
            width: 100%;
            /* height: 270px; */
            padding-bottom: 30%;
            position: relative;
        }
        .content_panel {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .icon_panel {
            height: 20%;
            display: inline-flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .link_btn {
            height: 100%;
        }
        .link_btn>img {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100%;
            width: auto;
        }
    </style>
```

#### My try

> When I set a fixed height for `outer_container`, Firefox give me a expected result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't height: 100% work to expand divs to the screen height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875/why-doesnt-height-100-work-to-expand-divs-to-the-screen-height) or this: [CSS height 100% percent not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357238/css-height-100-percent-not-working)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe this is not cause of this problem. `outer_container` height is up to `padding-bottom`, and `content_panel` is an absolute element. The height of the child element was set to 100% worked.Has a wrong understanding?. I'm a novice.

Comment: The parent must have a specified (not calculated) height for height:100% to work on a child. None of your elements have a height specified which is why it won't work for your image.

Comment: `img` has a correct scaling, but the `a` element width is the `img` width before scaling.